# sharepoint framework extensions: sorry something went wrong

Tags: error, debugging, spfx-extensions

I am trying to learn SharePoint Framework Extensions and this is my first try. I created an application customer following the example in pluralsight. When I try to add the app, I get the error: Sorry, somethin went wrong with adding the app.

I can't seem to get other information from UI. Could someone help me figure out how to troubleshoot this error? How can I view the logs using Get-SPOTenantLogEntry as at this moment I get nothing back?

[image]

Comment: why dont you debug using local workbench if in visual studios code? if you have it running on visual studios just debug as normal https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode in any case you need to provide more info. Bit hard to pinpoint what is going on with your code with no code or atleast what video your referring to ;)

Comment: When was the app deployed to app catalog ? Is your issue related to this :  https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1318#issuecomment-363352351 ?

Comment: @Ali Jafe, because it cannot be debugged using a workbench.

Comment: the app is deployed to app catalog. No, I don't think it is related to the one you posted.

Comment: Are you doing any feature framework provisioning? (element.xml) If so, there may be a conflict with the site. Providing details about what you're doing in the provisioning along with the version of the framework you are working with (latest is 1.4) would really help, thanks!

Comment: Also, while you can't debug SPFx Extensions in the workbenches, you can debug them on modern sites using querystrings without having to deploy them. The config\serve.json file will help you configure it so that when you use the `gulp serve` command it will build those parameters for you. Here's a blog I wrote about it: https://thechriskent.com/2017/11/03/utilizing-spfx-serveconfigurations/

Comment: Was this issue resolved? I'm facing the same issue..

Comment: @Frank H. Could you please click on the elipsis "..." of your app and then click on "Details", then under Error section, click on teh Install Errors link and see what the error is?

Comment: @BurreIfort Wow, this saved me. I have checked it earlier, but got a blank white page. I get this error now: The 'RegistrationType' attribute is invalid - The value 'DocumentLibrary' is invalid.

Comment: can you share a print screen of your error?
And can you make sure that you have a valid 1) CDN library 2) your elements.xml contains these exact properties, unless you are using other properties: ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;Top&quot;:&quot;The top&quot;,&quot;Bottom&quot;:&quot;The bottom&quot;}"

Try to remove the testMessage property from your elements.xml file and test it. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

I think I am trying the exact same pluralsight course and was having the same issue.  I got mine working now and in my case it was just a typo in the elements.xml file when defining ClientSideComponentProperties.  this may not be your issue but here is what it should look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CustomAction
        Title="Appcust"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer"
        ClientSideComponentId="d87f3988-5cae-4da0-bdfb-6882349b0d24"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;Top&quot;:&quot;The top&quot;,&quot;Bottom&quot;:&quot;The bottom&quot;}">        
    </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```